# Слово-фаворит: «д/Денди»

Tags: орфография

Нужны кавычки и нужно ли с большой буквы писать?

Слово-фаворит: «д/Денди».

Словосочетание-фаворит: «б/Бесхотдоговая таверна».

Любимое предложение: «р/Ретушёр съел чомгу».